# AWS Hive query for INPUT__FILE__NAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive

AWS Hive with GLUE metastore

i'm trying to get this query

```
select partition_name from mytable where
substr(reverse(split(reverse(INPUT__FILE__NAME), '/')[0]),5,8) = '20200705';
```

file names in S3 looks like **abc_20200705**

and get an issue from Glue

2020-08-11T23:20:55,496 FAILED: SemanticException InvalidObjectException(message:null (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 7f35e813-b495-4137-8eb7-c43cd09d))

is that possible to do **"where"** expression from INPUT__FILE__NAME virtual column?

Comment: how is your table created in Glue and also can you confirm if select INPUT__FILE__NAME from table is working fine?

Comment: select INPUT__FILE__NAME works fine
but when i try to do 'where' expression from it i receive an 400 error from Glue. I can't understand why it's happening
table created in glue as ddl request

Comment: all fields have String type

Comment: table has 2 partitions.
I tried to do the same request against table without partitions and it works.
So the question is, how we can do "where INPUT__FILE__NAME=' ' " agains tables with partitions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Glue doesn't support filtering INPUT__FILE__NAME on a partitioned table.  You can achieve this by using a subquery as shown below:

```
select
   partition_name 
from
   (
      select
         substr(reverse(split(reverse(INPUT__FILE__NAME), '/')[0]), 5, 8) as t,* from mytable
   )
   tmp 
where
   t = '20200705';
```

Comment: AWS support helped to solve that problem. set hive.optimize.ppd=false; Hive Predicate Push Down must be disabled if you want to use INPUT__FILE__NAME in "where" clause and Glue catalog as metastore.

Comment: So then your query will scan even more data when this is disabled?